# How can I provide an in app setting for double-length PseudoLanguage

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

In Xcode, you can edit a scheme and select double-length PseudoLanguage as the Application Language.

[image]

This works great for one off builds but I would like to add a UI toggle in the app which allows QA to toggle `double-length PseudoLanguage`.  The goal is for QA to go into a debug settings menu within the app and toggle `double-length PseudoLanguage` on or off.

Specifically, is there a way to toggle `double-length PseudoLanguage` in code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### tl;dr

You can change this setting from code by setting `true` for the `NSDoubleLocalizedStrings` key in `NSUserDefaults`. You must set this before you access any localizable strings so add the following to `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.

Swift:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "NSDoubleLocalizedStrings")
```

Objective-C

```
[NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults setBool:YES forKey:@"NSDoubleLocalizedStrings"];
```

Since this key is only read the first time your app accesses localizable strings, in order to change this at runtime for testing, you'll need to flip this boolean in `NSUserDefaults` and then kill and re-launch the app for it to take effect.

### More details:

Since the scheme setting from the screenshot you posted only applies when you run the app from Xcode, it won't affect archive builds. Instead you can do this by tapping into some nice features of launch arguments in iOS apps (may more details about this in [this talk]([this talk](https://www.skilled.io/u/swiftsummit/launch-arguments)).

Changing the settings in this tab of the scheme options, changes what extra launch arguments are sent to your binary when it is launched. For example, setting this language string results in Xcode passing `-NSDoubleLocalizedStrings` when you launch your app. You can see this behavior by creating a new Objective-C project, and adding this in `main.m` above the call to `UIApplicationMain`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
    NSLog(@"Argument %d: %s", i, argv[i]);
}
```

You can toggle the options in the scheme editor, and see specifically what strings get passed to your binary.

The next part of this is how iOS treats these launch arguments. The way the iOS SDK treats these, is by overlaying them on top of whatever the current `NSUserDefaults` values are set to. So in this case, this just sets `true` for `NSDoubleLocalizedStrings` at launch. This is why the above solution works.

Briefly, the reason this seems to not work if you change the flag at runtime, is because these settings are loaded the very first time you read a localizable string in your app inside a `dispatch_once`.